# How can i update selenium 2.45 to 3.9.1 in my project and also resolve organize new imports in the project?

Tags: selenium

I have built my project using selenium 2.45 but now i need to update it to 3.9.1.
When i am changing it in pom.xml .There are several errors in project of invalid imports. Do i need to correct in every file or there is better way to do it

Comment: rebuid your project again

Answer (score 0):

Use below steps to do the same:

1. Change the selenium jar file version from 2.45 to 3.9.1 in your `pom.xml` file and save it, It started downloading all new jar files in repository.
2. Now click <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> it will show dialog box to update the maven project as given below :

[image]

3. Click OK, it will clean and update all the configurations

**Note :** *Minimum version of Java required to run Selenium 3 is Java 8+* so update the java version

If still you face the issues regarding old imports and all then just delete the complete `.m2` from your `C:\Users\username` and update the project.